# Room: @Embedded vs @TypeConverters

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

Если у нас в Room есть @Entity в которых в качестве полей есть сложные объекты мы можем использовать 2 подхода:

- @Embedded - как я понимаю, если пометить поле этой анноташкой, то Room все поля которые находятся внутри объекта сохранит как поля самой Entity, а потом извлечет все корректно.
- @TypeConverters - тут мы пишем свой конвертер, который в большинстве случае сводится к обычному парсингу объекта в Json строку.

**Собственно вопрос:**

В чем принципиальная разница? Почему бы не писать везде @Embedded и не париться о всяких конверторах? Когда лучше писать свой конвертор, а когда лучше использловать @Embedded, и какие преимущества и недостатки дают эти подходы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помимо @Embedded и @TypeConverters, нужно еще не забывать о @Relation. Если бездумно использовать @Embedded то придется потом перелопатить всю таблицу. К примеру есть у нас User, внутри он содержит Address. Мы пометили его как @Embedded и room запишет все в одну таблицу. И тут надо нам добавить еще один адрес, и все @Embedded уже теряет актуальность. Так как его нельзя повесить на коллекцию. Тут стоит уже использовать связи. Еще один недостаток, это то что таблица становится слишком перегруженной. И будет хранить данные совсем разного толка, адреса, данные пользователей, марку его машины и так далее. Это в дальнейшем может выстрелить в ногу.

Что по поводу @TypeConverters. Я думаю он хорош если у вас вложенный список примитивов. Если конвертировать объекты, допустим с помощью Gson, в дальнейшем будет сложно осуществить выборку по какому-то из них. Допустим взять того же User со списком адресов. У адресов есть номер дома, индекс и так далее. Сковертируем мы это в Json. Запишем. Дальше нам понадобится найти юзера по индексу. Искать в json строках намного дороже чем искать обычный int.

По итогу все сводится к тому, как нам потом придется искать что-то в этих данных и придется ли вообще.

Answer (score 1):

`@Embedded` можно повесить лишь на конкретное поле/свойство, `@TypeConverters` помимо полей, можно повесить на Dao, Entity, БД (будут конвертиться все объекты подходящего типа в Dao, всей Entity, во всех Entity в БД соответственно). К тому же не на все типы получится использовать `Embedded`, например коллекции.

Comment: Хотелось бы более развернутые примеры. Просто пока, что складывается впечатление, что для листов только стоит писать конвертеры, а для всех остальных случаев нет. А то что применяется к Entity и конкретному полю, это в целом не аргумент. Ну типа проще написать аноташку в полю, чем к каждому полю писать конвертор.